# How to upgrade a package in linux that was built from source?

Tags: linux, boost, upgrade, package

I downloaded Boost v1.42 source and then installed it in my laptop. I want to upgrade them to v1.45 (the current release). I would like to know how I can do this via command line. This question applies to any package built from source and installed in a Linux machine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers...

**EDIT-1:** The distro I am using is CentOS 5 on my laptop and Debian Lenny on my PC.

Comment: Which Linux distro do you have? Is it a Debian variant or a RedHat variant?

Comment: Please see EDIT-1. Thanks for asking. But I guess the solution should be applicable to any distro, doesn't it?

Comment: This really belongs on superuser or unix.ste

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are building from source, then there is no concept of "upgrading" as there is no database where the version of the software is being registered (one of the features of a package manager). just build the new code exactly as you did the previous code.

Comment: To add to this: If you downloaded the source code as part of a source control repository, you can update the source code through that and then re-compile, be sure to make clean first though!