# Upgrading a package whose newest version is not still in the distribution repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, repository, upgrade, libpng

I need to upgrade libpng from version 1.2 to 1.5. I need to do so because of this: [libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.26 but running with 1.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182709/). I am using Lubuntu 11.10 and in the Canonical repositories libnpg 1.5 is not still released although at Debian ones there are testing packages (http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libpng) that at first they would fit to me. I added the Debian repositories to Synaptec and I was able to install libpng15, but those packages do not replace libpng12, son when it comes to compile some source code the IDE uses libpng12 instead of libpng15.

To try to solve this I downloaded the libpng15 deb package, uncompressed it and changed the *Replaces*, *Conflicts* and *Provides* tags of the *control* file with the *libpng15* text. Then, I executed the modified deb, but what I only got was a GDebi error and a general system failure because (I think) libpng12 was uninstalled with no replacement and Lubuntu heavily depends on it, which forced me to reinstall Lubuntu because the computer did not boot again in Linux. Yes, this solution is not the neatest way I think.

So, **is there any way to upgrade a package and replace the old version whose newer version exists but it is not still in the distribution repository?** I found [ubuntu repository for libpng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030593/ubuntu-repository-for-libpng) and [How to upgrade a package in linux that was built from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394718/how-to-upgrade-a-package-in-linux-that-was-built-from-source). Although not very determinant so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found out how to upgrade and replace a package whose newer version is not still in the distribution repository. But I have realized that if some library X relies on a given version of other library Y, there is no way to change the version of that dependence unless you make some change onto the source code of X, that is it, the library X is recompiled to point to the desired version (usually with the help of some configuration tag). Even though some trick could be done as by modifying the symlink of the library Y to point to the newer version. Then, the compiler will complain and ask for the old version.

Maybe this looks obvious now. But if the software that has to be recompiled requires many hours, has unresolved dependences or gives built errors you will try to avoid the compilation no matter if you are violating thermodynamics laws.

So in my case I had to recompile Qt and by using the -system-libpng configuration tag Qt understood it had to use system libpng libraries, not in-built ones. And after 8 hours of compiling I got a successfully built which solved this libpng problem.

Thanks everyone for the comments and suggests.

Comment: Glad you got your issue squared away. That's always a nice feeling. +1 for the update/closure.

Answer (score 1):

For all of the trouble you're going through, it might be easier to simply compile from source, and install to `/usr/local` (instead of `/usr`, as debs do). I've done this for several library dependencies for programs I've compiled (with make build systems) without any trouble. However, it sounds like the program(s) you're compiling are having trouble choosing the right version of the package. In my opinion, that is the real issue. Having multiple versions of a library installed simultaneously is supported, but perhaps not by apt in the case of mixing Debian and Ubuntu repos.

When you compile your program, use `gcc -lpng15` instead of `-lpng`. According to the gcc info manual, an option of `-lname` causes the linker to look for `libname.a` in the lib folders. On my system (Ubuntu 10.04), `libpng.a` is a symlink to `libpng12.a`. This is why your program is choosing the wrong lib.

Comment: Or better still, rebuild the package from its Debian sources on the local box.

Comment: Ah, well--I always prefer vanilla.

Comment: With `ldd program | grep libpng` I get `libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x007ec000)`. In which part of Linux could the reference to this library be changed?

Comment: I don't think it's a linux thing. It's a compiler option. I'm sorry I can't help more---I don't actually code C programs a lot, or their build systems; I just install them.

Comment: Actually, though, the error message and your ldd printout implies that 1.5 is what you have installed, and that 1.2 is what you *need* for the program to work, unless I'm missing something..

Comment: This is because when I compile my Qt program Qt uses a in-built libpng15 instead of the system default libpng12. Qt can be recompiled with the `-system-libpng` tag which changes this behaviour, but when I do so I get a compile error complaining about the system libpng do not match the version of the Qt libpng!! It is an infinite loop!!

Comment: Okay. Try this when you compile (link): `gcc -lpng15`. Check my answer's edit for more info.

Comment: At the g++ output there is any reference to something with *png*. So I guess the call to libpng is done from the Qt libraries (I do not do that from my code). If I add -lpng15 as preprocessor definition to my project g++ detects libpng15 but the compilation stops and gives the next error: `<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers`. I have done this with the libpng15s from Debian and Linaro PPA repositories.

Comment: Hmm. That's fun, isn't it? Well, this is a long shot, but maybe try recompiling Qt with `-system-libpng` (and telling it to use the 1.5 library, or temporarily changing the `libpng.a` symlink to point to `libpng15.a`). I haven't worked with Qt before, so I really don't know. Sorry.

Comment: Ups, the error I got was because I put the preprocessor definition in the wrong place. Nevertheless, when I added -lpng15 in the right place nothing changed. More information at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~linaro-maintainers/+archive/overlay. It contains libpng1.5 for Oneiric.

You can install it by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linaro-maintainers/overlay
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpng1.5
```

Comment: The problem of this package, as well as the one provided by Debian is it does not replace libpng12. So when I compile the reference libpng points to libpng12 instead of libpng15.

Answer (score 0):

To properly link against `libpng15`, you will also need to install `libpng15-dev`.